# ADO Recordset Number Field Doesn't Transfer Correctly for Spanish User

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have an Access database that is controlled by an Excel front end. 9 users in North America have no issues, the 10th user in Spain has issues with number formatting.

When a button is clicked, a PDF is created (which has correct formatting for all users) and a database entry is made. For the user who is in Spain, the cents separator is removed from the database entry.

I am using an ADO recordset to transfer the data, and all values are entered in textbox controls in Excel. I have tried separating the dollar and cent fields, and adding validation that no non numeric characters were entered. When the button is clicked, it combines the dollar and cent fields for the PDF and database entry.

```
Private Sub AmountBoxCents_AfterUpdate()

If CheckValuesForNonNumbers(AmountBoxCents.Value) = True Then
    If IsNumeric(AmountBox.Value Then
        AmountBoxTotal.Value = (Left(AmountBoxCents.Value, 2)) / 100 + AmountBox.Value
    End If
Else
    AmountBoxCents.Value = ""
End If

End Sub
```

CheckValuesForNonNumbers checks for letters or symbols in the just updated field. The IsNumeric portion then checks that the dollar amount isn't blank.

```
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection 'Connect to the Access database
With cnn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbLocation & "\" & dbName & ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" & DBPWord
    .Open dbLocation & "\" & dbName
End With


Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.Open "tblEFTRec", cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable

With rst
    .AddNew
        .Fields("CreatedBy") = Application.UserName
        .Fields("CreatedOn") = Now
        .Fields("Trans_Amnt") = AmountBoxTotal.Value
        .Fields("USD_Equ") = USDBox.Value
    .Update
End With


rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
cnn.Close
Set cnn = Nothing
```

The above code opens an ADO recordset from the tblEFTRec table, then adds a new record, adds to the fields, updates, and closes.

Comment: Can you provide the code for when it combines the cent and dollar amounts as well as the Recordset you are using?

Comment: When you say "correct formatting for all users" does that mean a comma or point as decimal separator for the Spanish client?

Comment: Yeah @arcadeprecint, for the PDF the North American users would get '123,456.78' and the Spanish user would get '123.456,78'. But for the database entry the North American user gets '123,456.78' while the Spanish user gets '12,345,678'

Comment: I think `.Fields("Trans_Amnt") = CDbl(AmountBoxTotal.Value)` should do it

Comment: @arcadeprecinct I will update my code and report back. Unfortunately it is now 7pm in Spain so testing will have to wait till tomorrow. Thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my best guess. If it's not the solution it might still help figuring it out: The Spanish system uses `,` as decimal separator. When assigning (string) value

```
AmountBoxTotal.Value = (Left(AmountBoxCents.Value, 2)) / 100 + AmountBox.Value
```

it produces a string with `,` as separator (which is good) **edit: or not, see example below** . Now when you do

```
.Fields("Trans_Amnt") = AmountBoxTotal.Value
```

a string gets passed and at some point converted back to double. I have no experience with ADO recordsets but it seems that that conversion is using a `.` as separator and dropping all `,` because they would just be thousands separators. By using `.Fields("Trans_Amnt") = CDbl(AmountBoxTotal.Value)` it should be converted back using the same separator as before and then passed as a number, not a string and should be fine.

Dealing with foreign number formats can be tricky when strings are involved. For example (tested on my German system):

```
AmountBoxTotal.Value = 1.5                      'AmountBoxTotal now shows "1.5"
AmountBoxTotal.Value = AmountBoxTotal.Value + 1 'AmountBoxTotal now shows "16"
'
AmountBoxTotal.Value = 3/2 'AmountBoxTotal now shows "1.5", same behavior as above
'
AmountBoxTotal.Value = "1,5"                    'AmountBoxTotal now shows "1,5"
AmountBoxTotal.Value = AmountBoxTotal.Value + 1 'AmountBoxTotal now shows "2.5"
AmountBoxTotal.Value = AmountBoxTotal.Value + 1 'AmountBoxTotal now shows "26"
'
AmountBoxTotal.Value = CStr(1.5) 'AmountBoxTotal now shows "1,5", same behaviour as above
```

So to sum up... I don't know. Why is it using `.` to display the number in the textbox?? I must admit though that I have an English installation of both Windows and Office using German date/time/number formats so maybe that's causing even more confusion? What separator I chose in the Excel settings had no effect on the above examples.

Comment: Everything you've said makes a lot of sense, so I'm really hopeful this might finally be resolved. I will definitely come back and mark as correct once I can test tomorrow.

Comment: @jcarroll I tried a little bit more and now it makes less sense, unfortunately... Good luck tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

First, you should always handle numbers like that, not strings. Don't know what this does:

```
If IsNumeric(AmountBox.Value) Then
    AmountBoxTotal.Value = (Left(AmountBoxCents.Value, 2)) / 100 + AmountBox.Value
End If
```

but it certainly isn't the optimal method.

Then, a localized formatted decimal can be converted with *CCur*:

```
.Fields("Trans_Amnt").Value = CCur(AmountBoxTotal.Value)
```

Comment: Hi Gustav, to answer your question. AmountBoxTotal contains the combined dollar and cent number. AmountBoxCents contains the cents portion, which is entered without a decimal or comma, so it needs to be divided by 100 to take it from 75 to 0.75. To your second comment, I believe that is the fix I needed, but I won't be able to test until tomorrow.

Comment: I see about the cents. But what kind of input do you expect since you apply `Left(.. , 2)`?

Comment: Someone accidentally created a record with 3 digits in the cents field, so my boss asked me to ensure that doesn't happen.